# Workaround to get the UserId from userRecordAccess?

Tags: apex, userrecordaccess

Is there anyway how we can get the `UserId` from `userRecordAccess`? It is not possible to query `UserId` from `userRecordAccess`.

```
SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess, UserId ,
                                                     HasDeleteAccess, 
                                                     HasEditAccess,
                                                     HasReadAccess, 
                                                     HasTransferAccess 
                                                FROM UserRecordAccess 
                                               WHERE UserId = '00550000000rlrX' 
                                                 AND RecordId = '0015000000TaWdI'
```

So does anyone have any work-around for that?

If we select `UserId` then get this error

> Can select only RecordId, a Has*Access field, and MaxAccessLevel

Would be of great help if you do!

Comment: UserId, must be in query criteria, but NOT in query result.

Comment: Yes, I know but is there a workaround? Any possible way to get the UserId from `userRecordAccess`?

Comment: I'm sorry but would you mind explaining? Dynamic query which object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't get UserId directly from this query. As you can only get UserRecordAccess for a Single user at a time.

Here is the query which you need to execute to get that.

```
SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess, HasDeleteAccess,  HasEditAccess, HasReadAccess,  HasTransferAccess  FROM UserRecordAccess where UserId= '00550000000rlrX' and RecordID = '0015000000TaWdI'
```

In addition to this you can't get **UserId** field, as you've to pass this Id in where filter so you already know which user records you're accessing.

Also you can't get It with the help of Dynamic Query.